# Angular - how to replace object properties with another object?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a question on what's the best way to achieve this, 
I have an array with 8 objects:

```
myArray = [ {id: 1, name, xxx, town: Town}, ...]
```

then I have a second array with another 8 objects of type `Town`:

```
townArray = [ {id: 1, name: RngTown}, ... ]
```

I subscribe to the first array, then I subscribe to the second, and what I want to achieve is a new array that fills the property `Town` of `myArray`, with the 8objects in `townArray`, order doesn't matter, it's just dummy data.

is map() the right way?

and in this example I have 8 objects in the first array, and 8 in the second, so each property `Town` will have a unique `Town` from the `second array`, but what would happen if I only had 6 `town` object? Can I map all of them to my 8objects, and when they finish after 6 `towns`, they start from the first `town` again until all objects in the first array have a `town`?

thank you

Comment: could you please eloborate what you want to achive. It's bit confusing at the moment. Do you want to update town in myArray with value from "townArray"?

Comment: exactly that, if myArray has 8 objects, and I have as well 8objects in the "townArray" of type Town, I want to assign to each town property, a town object from the second array, and would also like to know, if I didn't have 8 town objects in the second array, let's say I only had 6, how can I assign those 6 to the first 6 town properties, and the assign 2 more towns to the remaining 2 town properties? ofc at the end there will be town properties with the same town object as I would have only 6 different town objects, hope it s clear

Comment: let's say I only had 6, how can I assign those 6 to the first 6 town properties, and the assign 2 more towns to the remaining 2 town properties? meaning assigning town is random and there is no relationship between myArray and townArray, is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did an example here.
I think this will solve your issue!
What it does is assign the towns by the id, so the result 1 will have the town 1 and so on!
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k9rnkk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
let me know if you really want to use map.
Check in the console log the result!